# unable to connect to api.heroku.com

Tags: heroku, cloud, command-line-interface, connect

I am working with heroku from the site http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java.

My OS is windows7.

When I am typing the command heroku in command prompt I am getting the following:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\HARIKA_RAM>heroku
Usage: heroku COMMAND [--app APP] [command-specific-options]

Primary help topics, type "heroku help TOPIC" for more details:
```

It is working fine.

When I am trying to login it is giving the following message:

```
C:\Users\HARIKA_RAM>heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: evsandeep@gmail.com
Password:
 !    Unable to connect to api.heroku.com

C:\Users\HARIKA_RAM>heroku update
-----> Updating to latest client... failed
   !   getaddrinfo: This is usually a temporary error during hostname
resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an
authoritative server.
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've reformatted your post - four spaces in front of every console line improves readability hugely. If you could take the time to do a little formatting of questions before posting, it will improve your response/voting rate `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting your http_proxy if you are behind a firewall ?

eg. set http_proxy=proxy.mycompany.com:8080